# Como agregar propriedades de objetos em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Suponha um objeto da seguinte forma:

```
vendas = {
    obs1:{
        Venda1:{Regiao:"Norte", Valor: 200}, 
        Venda2:{Regiao:"Sul", Valor:100}
    }, 
    obs2:{
        Venda1:{Regiao:"Norte", Valor: 50}, 
        Venda2:{Regiao:"Sul", Valor:20}
    }
}
```

Como agregar a soma dos valores por região? É possível fazer isso sem loops?

O resultado seria um objeto como:

```
totais = {Norte:250, Sul:120}
```

As respostas podem ser em JS puro ou com bibliotecas.

Comment: Você topa usar uma biblioteca? A Underscore simplifica muito a solução.

Comment: Claro, o que eu quero no fundo é achar bibliotecas que facilitem manipulação de dados no JS. Mas perguntar isso seria muito aberto, então achei melhor dar um exemplo!

Comment: Bom, cheguei tarde e já tem uma boa resposta com underscore. Mas eu achava que o código ia ficar mais conciso usando essa biblioteca... Comparando com o código em JS puro, acho que eu acabaria usando o segundo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Com a biblioteca [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) dá pra fazer algo assim:

```
var totais = _
    .chain(vendas)
    // Primeiro: "achatar" as vendas
    .map(function(v) { 
        return _
            .chain(v)
            .map(function(v2) {
                return v2;
            })
            .value(); 
    })
    .flatten()
    // Segundo: agrupar as vendas por região
    .groupBy('Regiao')
    // Terceiro: somar os agrupamentos e criar o objeto com os totais
    .map(function(g, key) {
        return {
            type: key, 
            val: _(g).reduce(function(m, x) {
                return m + x.Valor;
            }, 0)
        };
    })
    .value();

console.log(totais);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/4Dbaq/1)

[Resposta do mgibsonbr para a mesma pergunta no SOEN (com generalização da solução)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521894/how-to-aggregate-objects-properties/23524971#23524971)

Comment: Boa solução, mas por que chamar `value` só para ter que usar `_()` de novo? http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/4Dbaq/1/

Comment: Pois é, assim é melhor! O pessoal estava me esperando pra almoçar aqui, fiz correndo! Hehehe.. (vou atualizar resposta)

Comment: Muito bom, cara, valeu mesmo! Fiz essa pergunta no SOEN, se quiser responder lá: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521894/how-to-aggregate-objects-properties . PS: O SOPT está muito melhor e mais receptivo do que o inglês, temos que manter assim.

Comment: Eu traduzi essa resposta e [postei no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23524971/520779), atribuindo a fonte para cá e acrescentando minhas próprias contribuições (i.e. generalizando a solução). Concordo que o SOpt está mesmo mais receptivo, embora lendo os comentários lá achei que alguns deles têm sim algum mérito (particularmente [este](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521894/how-to-aggregate-objects-properties/23524971#comment36080145_23521894)).

Comment: Muito interessante a sua generalização, parabéns!

Comment: @mgibsonbr não sei se concordo. Algumas respostas naturalmente serão mais generalizáveis que outras o importante é resolver o problema. Por exemplo, eu não precisei explicar que quero uma resposta generalizável aqui no SOpt e veio tanto uma resposta mais flexível quanto uma menos, e ambas trazem informação úteis. Acho que ncontraprodutivo esse inquérito do SOEN, sendo que cogitaram fechar a questão antes mesmo de deixarem respostas interessantes surgirem.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Concordo, às vezes gasta-se tempo demais discutindo se a pergunta é ou não apropriada ao site, quando as energias seriam melhor gastas *respondendo* a pergunta... O que eu disse que tinha mérito é o questionamento do que está sendo perguntado de fato: seria a presença ou não de uma forma funcional/declarativa? ("fazer sem loops") A generalização conforme a estrutura? (níveis de aninhamento, nomes das propriedades) Outra coisa? Aqui no SOpt entendemos rápido o que você queria, mas talvez lá eles não tenham achado a pergunta suficientemente clara.

Comment: @mgibsonbr estou tendo problema na hora de testar sua função "aggregate", ela não está encontrando a função "flatten" (erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: flatten is not defined). Será problema de escopo?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Eu testei no jsFiddle antes de postar no SOen, só não publiquei o fiddle porque fiquei com preguiça de traduzir pro inglês... :P http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/4Dbaq/2/ P.S. Ah, é mesmo: depois da edição - que mudava o nome da função pra `deepFlatten` - eu esqueci de mudar em uma parte. Já está corrigido!

Answer (score 6):

Para agregar os valores você pode usar a seguinte função:

```
function somarRegioes(vendas)
{
    totais = {};

    obs = Object.keys(vendas).map(function (key1) 
    {
        var obs_vendas = vendas[key1];

        Object.keys(obs_vendas).map(function (key2) 
        {
            var regiao = obs_vendas[key2]['Regiao'];

            // Se a região ainda não existir em totais.
            if(totais[regiao] === undefined) 
                totais[regiao] = 0;

            totais[regiao] += obs_vendas[key2]['Valor'];
        });
    });

    return totais;
}
```

Ou com essa:

```
function somarRegioes(vendas)
{
    totais = {};

    for(var obs in vendas)
    {
        for(var venda in vendas[obs])
        {
            var regiao = vendas[obs][venda]['Regiao'];

            // Se a região ainda não existir em totais.
            if(totais[regiao] == undefined) 
                totais[regiao] = 0;

            totais[regiao] += vendas[obs][venda]['Valor'];
        }
    }

    return totais;
}
```

O que fica como:

```
vendas = {obs1:{Venda1:{Regiao:"Norte", Valor: 200}, Venda2:{Regiao:"Sul", Valor:100}}, obs2:{Venda1:{Regiao:"Norte", Valor: 50}, Venda2:{Regiao:"Sul", Valor:20}}}
resultado = somarRegioes(vendas); // output = Object {Norte: 250, Sul: 120}
```

Acho um pouco complicado fazer isso sem loops, pois isso ocorrerá nem que seja indiretamente, pelo fato de que a entrada é dinâmica.

Answer (score 5):

Consegui uma forma ainda mais sintética utilizando o [jFunk](https://code.google.com/p/jfunk/) e [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce).

```
totais = _.chain(jF("*[Regiao]", vendas).get()).groupBy('Regiao').map(function(g, key) {
        return {
            type: key, 
            val: _(g).reduce(function(m, x) {
                return m + x.Valor;
            }, 0)
        };
    })
    .value();
```

Comment: Interessante esse jFunk, de fato JSON (e objetos JS) precisava de uma sintaxe de seleção tal como o XPath é para o XML. Pena que ainda é só um protótipo (ou prova-de-conceito), tomara que isso vá pra frente!