# Agrupar e somar array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Como fazer uma função para somar apenas os valores que sejam da mesma data?
Eu passando um  array de arrays:

```
[{ servicos: 0, remessa: 503, materiais: 0 , retorno: 598, entrada: 0, date: new Date("2011/12/20") },
{ servicos: 302, remessa: 0, materiais: 412 , retorno: 234, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/12/20") },
{ servicos: 276, remessa: 211, materiais: 0, retorno: 598, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/13/20") },
{ servicos: 543, remessa: 5033, materiais: 412 , retorno: 0, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/13/20") },
{ servicos: 876, remessa: 503, materiais: 412 , retorno: 0, entrada: 0, date: new Date("2011/13/20") }]
```

No exemplo acima, como retornar um array do dia 12 e outro do dia 13?

Comment: É isso que você está tentando fazer? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15064/como-agregar-propriedades-de-objetos-em-javascript/15074#15074

Comment: "(...)preciso de uma função(...)" O que você já tentou?

Comment: mas com a soma de vários índices, pela data, teria um exemplo?

Comment: Renan, tenho apenas a função que retorna, todos estes arrays, agora para agrupar, não sei como fazer

Comment: @Jhonatan Então fica uma dica: ao invés de "eu preciso de uma função...", diga "como faço para..." A primeira frase pode dar a impressão de que você não quer aprender e apenas que que alguém resolve seu problema por você. A segunda dá a impressão de que você está se esforçando pela solução. Assim as pessoas ficam mais dispostas a lhe ajudar ;)

Comment: Quais são os valores que quer somar? pode pelo menos dar um exemplo do formato final que pretende?

Comment: Renan, eu falei da função, pq o php tem a função q faz isso fácil, Sergio, o formato final é array msm

Comment: Só melhorar a questão que ela é muito boa, falta aprimorar e colocar um exemplo de saída!

Comment: @Jhonatan pode dar um exemplo? eu continuo sem perceber o que quer. Que valores devem ser adicionados com quais? Isto é bem simples de fazer mas só vou responder quando perceber o que quer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que o que você queira fazer seja isso:

```
var arr = [{ servicos: 0, remessa: 503, materiais: 0 , retorno: 598, entrada: 0, date: new Date("2011/12/20") },
           { servicos: 302, remessa: 0, materiais: 412 , retorno: 234, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/12/20") },
           { servicos: 276, remessa: 211, materiais: 0, retorno: 598, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/13/20") },
           { servicos: 543, remessa: 5033, materiais: 412 , retorno: 0, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/13/20") },
           { servicos: 876, remessa: 503, materiais: 412 , retorno: 0, entrada: 0, date: new Date("2011/13/20") }];

var result = new Object();
arr.filter(function (i){ 
  if(result.hasOwnProperty(i.date)){
    result[i.date].servicos += i.servicos;
    result[i.date].remessa += i.remessa;
    result[i.date].materiais += i.materiais;
    result[i.date].retorno += i.retorno;
    result[i.date].entrada += i.entrada;
  }else{
    result[i.date] = new Object();
    result[i.date].servicos = i.servicos;
    result[i.date].remessa = i.remessa;
    result[i.date].materiais = i.materiais;
    result[i.date].retorno = i.retorno;
    result[i.date].entrada = i.entrada;
  }
});
```

Isso te retornará um `Object` cuja a chave é a data. Para cada data ele salva os dados de cada entrada do objeto.

---

Caso seja realmente necessário utilizar um vetor, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
var arr = [{ servicos: 0, remessa: 503, materiais: 0 , retorno: 598, entrada: 0, date: new Date("2011/12/20") },
           { servicos: 302, remessa: 0, materiais: 412 , retorno: 234, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/12/20") },
           { servicos: 276, remessa: 211, materiais: 0, retorno: 598, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/13/20") },
           { servicos: 543, remessa: 5033, materiais: 412 , retorno: 0, entrada: 864, date: new Date("2011/13/20") },
           { servicos: 876, remessa: 503, materiais: 412 , retorno: 0, entrada: 0, date: new Date("2011/13/20") }];

var result = [];
arr.filter(function (i){ 
  var hasElement = false;
  var j;
  for(j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
    if(result[j].date.getTime() === i.date.getTime()){
      hasElement = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(hasElement){
    result[j].servicos += i.servicos;
    result[j].remessa += i.remessa;
    result[j].materiais += i.materiais;
    result[j].retorno += i.retorno;
    result[j].entrada += i.entrada;
  }else{
    result.push(i);
  }
});
```

Com essa entrada, esse `filter` retornará um `Array` com dois elementos na variável `result`.

Comment: Cara, é quase isso, gostaria apenas de alterar isso para ao invés do objeto ter o nome da data, ser um array com campo "data:"

Comment: Tem algum motivo específico? Porque, senão, é menos custosa essa solução. Caso tu queira acessar por data basta fazer um `for`, da seguinte forma `for( k in result`, que ele retornará todas as datas que tem informações.

Comment: é que preciso usar no chart do Kendo ui, e lá aceita [{},{},{}]

Comment: Nesse caso, eu vou adicionar uma forma alternativa na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Caso tenha mais de um array você pode agrupa-los usando a seguinte forma:

```
var first_json = {"name":"joe", "age":27};
var second_json = {"name":"james", "age":32};

var jsons = new Array();
jsons.push(first_json);
jsons.push(second_json);
```

Obtendo o Resultado:

```
jsons = [
    {"name":"joe", "age":27},
    {"name":"james", "age":32}
]
```

Já no caso do filtro você pode fazer desta forma:

```
var data = { "items":[ { "id": 1, "category": "cat1" }, {
"id": 2, "category": "cat2" }, { "id": 3, "category": "cat1" } ]};

var returnedData = $.grep(data.items, function(element, index){
      return element.id == 1;
});
// console.log(returnedData);

alert(returnedData[0].id + "  " + returnedData[0].category);
```